# Do you always use a second-level cache in Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate

Do you always use a second-level cache in Hibernate or do you first try it without and only use it when the performance goes down?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make it work first, then make it fast.  If you don't need caching, don't implement it.

Answer (score 3):

In the applications where I've been, the database is shared among several applications, some of them are not Java at all. So, the second-level cache is not an option for me in these situations, because I never know when some other app can update the db.

Answer (score 2):

My usage of Hibernate has always been in the context of another framework (Spring, for example), where enabling caching is nearly trivial.  A number of these projects have made use of caching via [ehcache](http://ehcache.sourceforge.net/) for some critical domain classes.

Having said that, this is another area where we have to make trade-offs between resources - balancing retrieval performance against memory usage.  Optimization without measurement has been shown again and again to be poor practice.

Collect metrics about the performance of your application.  Then decide how to address the slow spots.  Caching may be the least of  your worries.

Answer (score 1):

If you do things right (beware of select N+1, etc) performance should be acceptable without second-level cache for the vast majority of cases

Answer (score 1):

We first try it without and only use it when the performance goes down.

Answer (score 0):

To quote the famous Donald Knuth: "Programmers waste enormous amounts of time thinking about, or worrying about, the speed of noncritical parts of their programs, and these attempts at efficiency actually have a strong negative impact when debugging and maintenance are considered. We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil. Yet we should not pass up our opportunities in that critical 3%."

If you are seeing performance issues, only then you can begin to optimize. And you should only optimize the largest bottleneck and work your way down if needed.

However, implementing this optimization in NHibernate has negligible impact on debugging and maintenance in most situations, and can often be implemented with very minimal additions to the code.

If you rely extensively on lazy loading, have read only tables, do not have to worry about concurrency with applications not using NHibernate, performance is an issue, and you are knowledgeable about how to optimize using 2nd level cache (meaning you already know the answer to this question), then you should use a second level cache.

Answer (score 0):

Now there is a hibernate specific issue that relates to this. And that the infamous LazyInitializationException. Basically you need to initialize all lazy associations while entities are attached to persistence context. Two ways to do this:

1. Manually access the relationships to force load them.
2. Use a query specifying a join fetch.

These two approaches result in a quite different code pieces so migrating one to the other can be quite a job. The problem is that approach 1. results in large number of queries when not using the 2nd level cache, so people can decide to use the approach 2 which results in fever queries. However, when you turn the 2nd level cache on later, the queries from approach 2 don't load data from the cache but do put resulting entities into it, making the query execution slower than it was without the cache. That leads to complicated things like having to use the query cache.

Because of that it seems better approach to me (in this particular case) to enable cache at first for all entities, which is usually trivial, and then disable it for entities you don't need it for as the development goes on.